# Do Titans have different amounts of shields?

Tags: titanfall

The Ogre chassis has quite a bit more armour than the Stryder, of course, but is there also a difference in the strength of their respective shields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Titans all have the same base shield strength and recharge time.** This is from decrypted files found during the beta, and remains true at the current patch level (as of 3/14/2014). The only stat variation between the chassis (besides the core ability) are speed and health.

The Ogre shield core halves all shield damage taken for it's duration, effectively doubling current shields while active.

[Source](http://denkirson.proboards.com/post/177877/thread)

> It seems all titan Shields are 2250 health. It takes six seconds
>   before they begin recharging after taking damage and two more seconds
>   to fully recharge.

Answer (score 2):

According to IGN, [the Ogre chassis can have an increased shield capacity for 15 seconds.](http://www.ign.com/wikis/titanfall/Ogre) It is the core ability, but you have to have it available.

Comment: And of course select it in the Titan configuration.